# boost udp receiver on windows and linux

Tags: sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a simple udp application written using boost:asio, where udp unicast receiver runs on windows and  unicast sender runs on linux .   My unicast sender on linux sent the packet successfully , but reciver on windows does not any packets , but I could see that packets sent by sender on wireshark which is running on windows . below is my udp receiver code (which is based on the sample provided my boost libs).

```
 class unicast_Receiver
 {
 public:
   unicast_Receiver(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint end1)
     : socket_(io_service)
   {


     socket_.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
     //socket_.open(end1.protocol());
     socket_.bind(end1);
     socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
     std::cout  << " >> on  " <<socket_.local_endpoint()<<" :: @"  << __LINE__ << __FUNCTION__   <<std::endl;
     start_receive();

   }

 private:
   void start_receive()
   {
      std::cout  << "\n !!!!Waiting in the Unicast Data Receive >> on  " << Unicastlisten_endpoint_ <<" :: @"  << __LINE__ << __FUNCTION__   <<std::endl;
     socket_.async_receive_from(
           boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), remote_endpoint_,
         boost::bind(&unicast_Receiver::handle_receive, this,
           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
   }

   void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
       std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
   {
     if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
     {

       std::cout  << "Unicast Data Received >> " <<"<< @"  << __LINE__ << __FUNCTION__   <<std::endl;
      std::cout << "\n" <<  data_  << "\n";
      memset(data_,0,max_length);
      start_receive();
     }
   }

   void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> /*message*/,
       const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
       std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
   {
   }


   udp::socket socket_;
   udp::endpoint remote_endpoint_;
   enum { max_length = 1024 };
   char data_[max_length];
   boost::array<char, 1> recv_buffer_;
 };


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   boost::asio::io_service io_serviceSe;
   boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint  Unicastlisten_endpoint_(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));
   unicast_Receiver server(io_serviceSe,Unicastlisten_endpoint_);
 }
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? What is the last think the Receiver prints out?

Comment: it prints the  below cout  !!!!Waiting in the Unicast Data Receive 192.168.1.121:56779 @ 351 start_receive

Comment: Wait you don't `io_serviceSe.run()` at any point, do you? Or am i blind? If you don't run, the async operation will never be posted. While i am personally not a fan of having the `start_receive` in the constructor, it should still work if you just call `io_serviceSe.run()` right after having created the server and before the main ends. Of course, right now your server will not stop unless it encounters a problem while receiving but that is another point.

Comment: By the way, as it is, `Unicastlisten_endpoint_` in your implementation has to be the local endpoint. So i assume 192.168.1.121 is the ip address of one of your local interfaces.

Comment: I added io_serviceSe.run() .. and 192.168.1.121 is my local endpoint only .. but still I am not able to get the packets.

Comment: I would suggest you edit it also into the code above so future readers can see it. And now with the run() in there, does the program hang without receiving and no further output or does it finish after the output you mentioned (i would add that information to the question as well)?